# Curious behaviour of c_str() and strings when passed to class

Tags: c++, string, c-str

I came across a curious behaviour (and I am sure it is just curious to me and there exists a perfectly valid c++ answer) when playing around with c-strings and std::string. Typically, when I pass a string to a class' constructor, I do something like this:

```cpp
class Foo {
public:
  Foo(const std::string& bar) bar_(bar) { }
private:
  const std::string& bar_;
};

int main() {
  Foo("Baz");
  return 0;
}
```

which thus far has worked quite well and I have (perhaps naively?) never question this approach.

Then recently I wanted to implement a simple data containing class which, when stripped to its essential structure, looked like this:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

class DataContainer {
public:
  DataContainer(const std::string& name, const std::string& description)
  : name_(name), description_(description) {}
  auto getName() const -> std::string { return name_; }
  auto getDescription() const -> std::string { return description_; }
private:
  const std::string& name_;
  const std::string& description_;
};

int main() {
    auto dataContainer = DataContainer{"parameterName", "parameterDescription"};
    auto name = dataContainer.getName();
    auto description = dataContainer.getDescription();

    std::cout << "name: " << name.c_str() << std::endl;
    std::cout << "description: " << description.c_str() << std::endl;
}
```

The output is:

```sh
name: parameterName
description:
```

I use `*.c_str()` here as this is how I use it my actual codebase (i.e. with google test and `EXPECT_STREQ(s1, s2)`.

When I remove `*.c_str()` in the main function I get the following output:

```sh
name: parameterName
description: tion
```

So the original string of the description is truncated and the initial string is missing. I was able to fix this by changing the type within the class to:

```cpp
private:
  const std::string name_;
  const std::string description_;
```

Now I get the expected output of

```sh
name: parameterName
description: parameterDescription
```

Which is fine, I can use this solution, but I would like to understand what is going on here. Also, if I change my main function slightly to

```cpp
int main() {
    auto dataContainer = DataContainer{"parameterName", "parameterDescription"};
    auto name = dataContainer.getName().c_str();
    auto description = dataContainer.getDescription().c_str();

    std::cout << "name: " << name << std::endl;
    std::cout << "description: " << description << std::endl;
}
```

it doesn't matter how I store the string within the `DataContainer` class, i.e. by const ref or value. In both cases, I get

```sh
name: parameterName
description:
```

along with a warning on clang:

```sh
<source>:19:17: warning: object backing the pointer will be destroyed at the end of the full-expression [-Wdangling-gsl]
    auto name = dataContainer.getName().c_str();
```

So I guess the issue is arising from *.c_str() itself? However, then I don't quite understand why I can't store the two strings name and description by const ref. Could anyone shed some light on the issue?

Comment: You store dangling references to temporaries...

Comment: `auto getName() const -> std::string` return copy... You should do `auto getName() const -> const std::string&`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As already noted, the problems in the posted code rise from dangling references to temporary objects, either stored as class members or returned and accessed by `.c_str()`.

The first fix is to store actual `std::string`s as members, not (dangling) references and then write accessor functions returning const references to those:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

class DataContainer {
public:
  DataContainer(std::string name, std::string description)
    : name_(std::move(name)), description_(std::move(description)) {}
  auto getName() const -> std::string const& { return name_; }
  auto getDescription() const ->  std::string const& { return description_; }
private:
  const std::string name_;
  const std::string description_;
};

int main() {
    auto dataContainer = DataContainer{"parameterName", "parameterDescription"};
    
    std::cout << "name: " << dataContainer.getName().c_str() << std::endl;
    std::cout << "description: " << dataContainer.getDescription().c_str() << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

You can see [here](https://godbolt.org/z/Pob8rnrnj) that the output is as expected (even [when](https://godbolt.org/z/cKPn37Kjr) using intermediate local variables).

---

> I  use `*.c_str()` here as this is how I use it my actual codebase

Then consider adding a couple of accessors returning [exactly that](https://godbolt.org/z/WvGPMoj94):

```cpp
//...
auto Name() const { return name_.c_str(); }
auto Description() const { return description_.c_str(); }
//...
std::cout << "name: " << dataContainer.Name() << std::endl;
std::cout << "description: " << dataContainer.Description() << std::endl;
```

Answer (score 1):

In the first issue, where you store `const std::string&` references as class members, you store *dangling references to temporary objects*.

When you pass string literals to your constructor, they are not themselves `std::string` objects, they are `const char[]` arrays. So, the compiler has to create *temporary* `std::string` objects to satisfy the constructor's parameters, which you then store references to.  Once the constructor exits, those temporaries get destroyed, leaving your stored references bound to invalid memory.

Your fix to store copies of the `std::string` objects rather than references to the originals is the correct solution.

---

In the second issue, where you call `c_str()` on the return values of `getName()` and `getDescription()`, it is a similar issue.  You are using *dangling pointers to temporary memory*.

Those methods are returning `std::string` objects *by value*, thus the compiler creates temporary copies of them at the call site.  `c_str()` returns a pointer to the internal data of a `std::string` object, and you store those pointers to local variables.  But then the temporaries get destroyed when they go out of scope, leaving your variables pointing to invalid memory before you have a chance to use them.

You can fix that in one of three ways:

- by saving *copies* of the `std::string` objects to the local variables, rather than saving their internal data pointers. This is what your `main()` code was originally doing:

```cpp
auto dataContainer = DataContainer{"parameterName", "parameterDescription"};
auto name = dataContainer.getName(); // <-- auto is deduced as std::string, name is a copy...
auto description = dataContainer.getDescription(); // <-- auto is deduced as std::string, description is a copy...

std::cout << "name: " << name.c_str() << std::endl; // <-- using c_str() pointer is safe here
std::cout << "description: " << description.c_str() << std::endl; // <-- using c_str() pointer is safe here
```

- by dropping the local variables altogether and using the `c_str()` pointers directly in the `cout` statements before the temporary `std::string` objects go out of scope:

```cpp
auto dataContainer = DataContainer{"parameterName", "parameterDescription"};

std::cout << "name: " << dataContainer.getName().c_str() << std::endl; // <-- getName() returns a temp copy, but c_str() is safe to use here
std::cout << "description: " << dataContainer.getDescription().c_str() << std::endl; // <-- getDescription() returns a temp copy, but c_str() is safe to use here
```

- by having the methods return *references* to the `std::string` class members, rather than returning *copies* of them:

```cpp
auto getName() const -> const std::string& { return name_; }
auto getDescription() const -> const std::string& { return description_; }
```

```cpp
auto dataContainer = DataContainer{"parameterName", "parameterDescription"};
auto name = dataContainer.getName().c_str(); // <-- no temp is returned here
auto description = dataContainer.getDescription().c_str(); // <-- no temp is returned here

std::cout << "name: " << name << std::endl; // using c_str() pointer is safe here!
std::cout << "description: " << description << std::endl; // <-- using c_str() pointer is safe here!
```

In this last case, just be sure not to modify the `std::string` class members before you use the pointers you have saved, otherwise the pointers could become invalidated.

Comment: Thanks for the additional insights. I have tested these things indeed beforehand as well, but the behaviour is the same (hence the title curious behaviour ...). Your first solution: https://godbolt.org/z/r16xnjqa6 , second solution: https://godbolt.org/z/KaPGrWWqz , third solution: https://godbolt.org/z/TxoMfe3Pe ... they all produce the original output (i.e. the name shows but the description doesn't). Tested on GCC 11.1 and Clang 12.0.0

Comment: Yup, all three of those godbolt examples are suffering from the same issue - storing dangling references to temporary objects

Answer (score 0):

The following is happening: you’re returning the `std::string` by copy (i.e. a temporary). Then `c_str()` will return a pointer to data within that temporary, which will be destroyed after the statement. Hence the warning. Return `const std::string&` instead to get rid of it.